# UITableView accessory view

Tags: ios

I have created a UITableView populated by data coming from mysql (using NSJSONSERIALIZATION). Now the problem is one thing. What I retrieved was the product name. I want to have an accessory view (arrow like on the right side of cell). once clicked, new view and load details of that product there.

I know it can be done, but don't know how or where to look for a good tutorial. Any recommendations?

am really new to iOS development.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Use this tableview delegate.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

...and in cellForRowAtIndexPath: add this.

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```